# Interpretation and application of PCA - positive factor patterns for first component for all variables

Tags: pca, multivariate-analysis

I am attempting to reduce the number of variables in a dataset for regression purposes and I suspect that many of the variables are correlated. Hence, I attempt a PCA, which I must admit I'm very new at. The variables in question are a range of indices, all ranging from 0 to 100.

After running PCA, I identify 3 components with eigenvalues greater than 1 (see results attached), with strong patterns for all variables in the first component.

Now I'm unsure how to proceed when it comes to using this information to apply to my regression, notably if factor patterns are strong for all variables in the first component, does that render the two others meaningless? How do I use this information to limit the number of variables in my regression model and avoid collinearity?

[image: PCA results]

Comment: PCA as a way of selecting predictors is a dark art and there are many arguments against, but only rarely do people who think it's a really bad idea write papers explaining why or explain why not to do it in their regression texts. Two more neutral comments: 1. You mention PCA but then talk about factors: people positive on PCA usually dislike FA intensely, and vice versa, so either way be consistent on terminology. Your software may be letting you down here. 2. The first PC or factor being dominant is typically a reflection of variables mostly being size or abundance measures.

Comment: The simplest argument against in my view is that if you have difficulty interpreting the components, quite what you have achieved in your regression won't be easy to interpret either. (And I often have difficulty in interpreting components.) I would focus on identifying important variables either substantively or from their correlations with the outcome variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When applying PCA to reduce the number of variables in a regression model, you would typically use the first few components with large eigenvalues as they explain the majority of the variance in the data. In your case, the first component appears to have strong patterns for all variables, but it's still important to consider the second and third components as they might also contain valuable information.

To avoid collinearity, you could use the first few components as your new independent variables in the regression model instead of the original variables. This is because the components are orthogonal and uncorrelated, which helps to reduce the risk of multicollinearity.

Additionally, you could consider interpreting the factor loadings for each variable to see how much of each variable's variance is explained by each component. This can help you determine which variables are contributing the most to the first component and if there are any outliers that might affect your regression results.

Finally, it's always a good idea to visualize the data and the results of the PCA to gain a better understanding of the relationships between the variables and components.